# plpgsql error "RETURN NEXT cannot have a parameter in function with OUT parameters" in table-returning function

Tags: database, postgresql, exception, plpgsql, return-next

I have a plpgsql function in PostgreSQL 9.2 which returns a table. The function runs several `SELECT`s that return the same columns as the function and then either returns those results or raises an exception, depending on some checks. The only way I can see of doing this is with `FOR ... LOOP`, but I can't figure out a convenient way of returning the row.

I want to do something like this:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_function()
RETURNS TABLE(column1 integer, column2 boolean, ...)
AS $BODY$
DECLARE
  result_row RECORD;
BEGIN
  FOR result_row IN (SELECT * FROM other_function_returning_same_columns()) LOOP
    IF something_wrong_with(result_row) THEN
      RAISE EXCEPTION 'Something went wrong';
    END IF;
    
    RETURN NEXT result_row;
  END LOOP;
END
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql STABLE;
```

This gives me an error:

> ERROR: RETURN NEXT cannot have a parameter in function with OUT parameters

I'm not sure why Postgres is complaining here, because my code looks a lot like the example in the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html), except that my function returns TABLE instead of SETOF. There are no OUT parameters.

I eventually managed to get it to work using:

```sql
RETURN QUERY SELECT result_row.column1, result_row.column2, ...;
```

But having to list all the columns all the time is ugly and harder to maintain. I'm sure there must be a better way.

Comment: Do you *need* an exception thrown, or do you just want qualifying rows back?

Comment: Yes, I do want an exception thrown in some cases.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

[**`RETURN NEXT`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/plpgsql-control-structures.html#id-1.8.8.8.3.4) just returns what output parameters currently hold. [The manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/plpgsql-control-structures.html#id-1.8.8.8.3.4):

> If you declared the function with output parameters, write just `RETURN NEXT` with no expression.

You object:

> There are no `OUT` parameters.

Output parameters are declared among function parameters with the keyword `OUT` or `INOUT`, **or** implicitly in your `RETURNS` clause:

```
RETURNS TABLE(column1 integer, column2 boolean, ...)
```

Here, `column1` and `column2` are `OUT` parameters, too.

This should do it:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_function()
  RETURNS TABLE(column1 integer, column2 boolean, ...)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql STABLE AS
$func$
BEGIN
   FOR column1, column2, ... IN 
      SELECT * FROM other_function_returning_same_columns()
   LOOP
      IF something_wrong_with(column1, column2, ...) THEN
         RAISE EXCEPTION 'Something went wrong';
      END IF;

      RETURN NEXT;
   END LOOP;
END
$func$;
```

#### Simpler with a registered type

You can further simplify with a registered composite type:

```
CREATE TYPE mytype (column1 integer, column2 boolean, ...);
```

Or, if your type happens to match a table definition, you already have that type, because every table name can be used as type name in PostgreSQL. Then simplify:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_function()
  RETURNS SETOF mytype
  LANGUAGE plpgsql STABLE AS
$func$
DECLARE
   _r mytype;
BEGIN
   FOR _r IN 
     SELECT * FROM other_function_returning_same_columns()
   LOOP
      IF something_wrong_with(_r) THEN
         RAISE EXCEPTION 'Something went wrong';
      END IF;

      RETURN NEXT _r;
   END LOOP;
END
$func$;
```

#### Reorganize!

If you integrate the `RAISE` command into your helper function `something_wrong_with()`, invert the logic and more conveniently name it `everything_groovy()`, then you can completely replace `my_function()` with this simple query:

```
SELECT *
FROM   other_function_returning_same_columns() f
WHERE  everything_groovy(f);
```

Or integrate the `RAISE` into the base function `other_function_returning_same_columns()` to further simplify (and make it faster). If you only want to `RAISE EXCEPTION` in certain situations, you can always add a parameter (with a default) to switch it on / off.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like I have to list all the columns whatever I do, but this is less code than what I had before.

Comment: @EM: Well, there are always more options. I added alternatives to my answer.

Comment: Thanks again! Putting the check into another function is an interesting idea. It won't really help in this case, because the real code is more complex than my example, but there may be other functions where I can use this trick instead of looping over results. (It would work here, but would be more complex than listing the columns.)

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error below:

> ERROR:  RETURN NEXT cannot have a parameter in function with OUT parameters

When I tried to create `my_func()` which has the `RETURNS TABLE()` with `f_n` and `l_n` parameter and the [RETURN NEXT statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING-RETURN-NEXT) with `row` as shown below:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func() RETURNS TABLE(f_n TEXT, l_n TEXT) AS $$
DECLARE                -- ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ Here ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ 
  row RECORD;
BEGIN
  FOR row IN VALUES ('John','Smith'), ('David','Miller') LOOP
    RETURN NEXT row; -- Here
  END LOOP;
  RETURN;
END;    
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

So, I removed `row` local variable from `RETURN NEXT` as shown below, then I could create `my_func()` without error:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func() RETURNS TABLE(f_n TEXT, l_n TEXT) AS $$
DECLARE
  row RECORD;
BEGIN
  FOR row IN VALUES ('John','Smith'), ('David','Miller') LOOP
    RETURN NEXT /* row */; -- Here
  END LOOP;
  RETURN;
END;    
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

But, calling `my_func()` returned empty rows as shown below:

```sql
postgres=# SELECT my_func();
 my_func
---------
 (,)
 (,)
(2 rows)
```

So, I set `f_n` and `l_n` parameter to the [FOR statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-RECORDS-ITERATING) instead of `row` local variable as shown below:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func() RETURNS TABLE(f_n TEXT, l_n TEXT) AS $$
-- DECLARE
  -- row RECORD;
BEGIN
  FOR f_n, l_n IN VALUES ('John','Smith'), ('David','Miller') LOOP
    RETURN NEXT /* row */; -- Here
  END LOOP;
  RETURN;
END;    
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Then, calling `my_func()` returned expected non-empty rows as shown below:

```sql
postgres=# SELECT my_func();
    my_func
----------------
 (John,Smith)
 (David,Miller)
(2 rows)
```

Be careful, if you assign `row` local variable to `f_n` and `l_n` parameter in the `FOR` statement as shown below:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func() RETURNS TABLE(f_n TEXT, l_n TEXT) AS $$
DECLARE
  row RECORD;
BEGIN
  FOR row IN VALUES ('John','Smith'), ('David','Miller') LOOP
    f_n := row;
    l_n := row;
    RETURN NEXT /* row */; -- Here
  END LOOP;
  RETURN;
END;    
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Then, calling `my_func()` returns unexpected non-empty rows as shown below:

```sql
postgres=# SELECT my_func();
               my_func
-------------------------------------
 ("(John,Smith)","(John,Smith)")
 ("(David,Miller)","(David,Miller)")
(2 rows)
```

In addition, you can create `my_func()` which has `RETURNS TABLE()` and [RETURN QUERY statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING-RETURN-NEXT) without error as shown below:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func() RETURNS TABLE(f_n TEXT, l_n TEXT) AS $$
BEGIN                  -- ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ Here ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑
  RETURN QUERY VALUES ('John','Smith'), ('David','Miller');
END; -- ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ Here ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Then, calling `my_func()` returned expected non-empty rows as shown below:

```sql
postgres=# SELECT my_func();
    my_func
----------------
 (John,Smith)
 (David,Miller)
(2 rows)
```