# ERROR: cannot use RETURN NEXT in a non-SETOF function

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, aggregate-functions, return-next

I have two tables with date-columns (year, month, day and a combination of the three called "stamp") and associated values (avalue). I need my function to return the ratio between two tables (at a specified date), return a fixed value after a previously-specified limit-date, and if the date is not available in the data (but lower than the limit), it should choose the first available date following the input.

Here's the code I wrote:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myfunction(theyear int, themonth int, theday int) RETURNS real AS '
DECLARE
  foo tablenamea%rowtype;
BEGIN
  IF ((theyear >= 2000) AND (themonth >= 6)) OR (theyear > 2000) THEN
    RETURN 0.1;
  ELSE 
    FOR foo IN SELECT (a.avalue/b.avalue) FROM tablenamea AS a, tablenameb AS b
      WHERE a.stamp = b.stamp AND a.year = theyear AND a.month = themonth AND a.day >= theday ORDER BY a.year, a.month, a.day
    LOOP
      RETURN NEXT foo;
    END LOOP;
    RETURN;
  END IF;
END;
' LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

This keeps giving me this error:

> ERROR: cannot use RETURN NEXT in a non-SETOF function

Answer (score 1):

It's telling you that you should return a real, instead of foo (which is a row).

Probably return `foo.somefield` instead.

Also, add a `limit 1` instead of a `for` loop, since I presume you're only really interested in the first row. If not, declare it as returning e.g. `table (ratio real)` and use `return query`.

Comment: Thank you. I'm really sorry to ask, but I'm very new to PL/pgSQL and I'm having some difficulty implementing your suggestions. Do you think you could possibly post what you mean in code?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error below:

> ERROR:  cannot use RETURN NEXT in a non-SETOF function

When I tried to create `my_func()` which has `RECORD` type in a `RETURNS` clause and [RETURN NEXT statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING-RETURN-NEXT) as shown below:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func() RETURNS RECORD AS $$
DECLARE                        -- ↑ ↑ ↑
  row RECORD;
BEGIN
  FOR row IN VALUES ('John', 'Smith'), ('David', 'Miller') LOOP
    RETURN NEXT row; -- Here
  END LOOP;
END;    
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

*Memos:

- I also got and solved [the same kind of error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55688418/what-is-a-non-setof-function/77985413#77985413) with a [RETURN QUERY statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING-RETURN-NEXT).

So, I set `SETOF RECORD` type to the `RETURNS` clause as shown below, then I could create `my_func()` without error:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func() RETURNS SETOF RECORD AS $$
DECLARE                        -- ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑
  row RECORD;
BEGIN
  FOR row IN VALUES ('John', 'Smith'), ('David', 'Miller') LOOP
    RETURN NEXT row;
  END LOOP;
END;    
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Then, I could call `my_func()` in a `FROM` clause without error as shown below:

```sql
postgres=# SELECT * FROM my_func() AS (f_n TEXT, l_n TEXT);
  f_n  |  l_n
-------+--------
 John  | Smith
 David | Miller
(2 rows)
```

Or, I set `TABLE()` type to the `RETURNS` clause, then I set `f_n` and `l_n` parameter to the [FOR statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-RECORDS-ITERATING) instead of `row` local variable as shown below. *If you set `row` local variable to the `RETURN NEXT` statement, there is [the error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14039720/plpgsql-error-return-next-cannot-have-a-parameter-in-function-with-out-paramete#77958122):

```sql
                               -- ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓
CREATE FUNCTION my_func() RETURNS TABLE(f_n TEXT, l_n TEXT) AS $$
-- DECLARE
  -- row RECORD;
BEGIN
  FOR f_n, l_n IN VALUES ('John', 'Smith'), ('David', 'Miller') LOOP
    RETURN NEXT /* row */;
  END LOOP;
END;    
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Then, I could call `my_func()` without error as shown below:

```sql
postgres=# SELECT * FROM my_func();
  f_n  |  l_n
-------+--------
 John  | Smith
 David | Miller
(2 rows)
```

```sql
postgres=# SELECT my_func();
    my_func
----------------
 (John,Smith)
 (David,Miller)
(2 rows)
```