# What is a "non-SETOF function" in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, plpgsql, return-query

Getting into PL/pgSQL…

I'm still learning the syntax. Sometimes, I'd run into this error message:

> ERROR: cannot use RETURN QUERY in a non-SETOF function

This sounds sort of cryptic and I could not find information in the Postgres documentation. Hence the question:

- What's a non-SETOF function?

And likewise, assuming there's such a thing, what's a SETOF function?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> What's a non-SETOF function?

It's a function returning a single (scalar) value, e.g. an `integer` or a `varchar`, e.g.

```
select upper('foo')`
```

`upper()` is a "non-SETOF" function, it only returns a single value. So a function that is e.g. defined as `returns integer` can't return the complete result of a SELECT query, it needs to use `return 42;` but it can't use `return query ...`;

---

> what's a SETOF function?

It's a function that returns a result set - similar to a table (it's typically declared as `returns table (...)`. And you can use it like a table:

```
select *
from some_set_returning_function();
```

Comment: Just to add, returning a row would also make a function "non-SETOF".

Answer (score 1):

As the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/xfunc-sql.html) says:

> an SQL function can be declared to return a set (that is, multiple rows) by specifying the function's return type as `SETOF sometype`, or equivalently by declaring it as `RETURNS TABLE(columns)`. In this case all rows of the last query's result are returned.

For instance, if it returns a row or a scalar it would be a non-SETOF.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error below:

> ERROR:  cannot use RETURN QUERY in a non-SETOF function

When I tried to create `my_func()` which has `RECORD` type in a RETURNS clause and [RETURN QUERY statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING-RETURN-NEXT) as shown below:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func() RETURNS RECORD AS $$
BEGIN                          -- ↑ ↑ ↑
  RETURN QUERY VALUES ('John', 'Smith'), ('David', 'Miller') LOOP
END;    
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

*Memos:

- I also got and solved [the same kind of error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17570450/error-cannot-use-return-next-in-a-non-setof-function#77975932) with a [RETURN NEXT statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING-RETURN-NEXT).

So, I set `SETOF RECORD` type to the `RETURNS` clause as shown below, then I could create `my_func()` without error:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func() RETURNS SETOF RECORD AS $$
BEGIN                          -- ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑
  RETURN QUERY VALUES ('John', 'Smith'), ('David', 'Miller');
END;    
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Then, I could call `my_func()` in a `FROM` clause without error as shown below:

```sql
postgres=# SELECT * FROM my_func() AS (f_n TEXT, l_n TEXT);
  f_n  |  l_n
-------+--------
 John  | Smith
 David | Miller
(2 rows)
```

Or, I set `TABLE()` type to the `RETURNS` clause as shown below:

```sql
                               -- ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓
CREATE FUNCTION my_func() RETURNS TABLE(f_n TEXT, l_n TEXT) AS $$
BEGIN
  RETURN QUERY VALUES ('John', 'Smith'), ('David', 'Miller');
END;    
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Then, I could call `my_func()` without error as shown below:

```sql
postgres=# SELECT * FROM my_func();
  f_n  |  l_n
-------+--------
 John  | Smith
 David | Miller
(2 rows)
```

```sql
postgres=# SELECT my_func();
    my_func
----------------
 (John,Smith)
 (David,Miller)
(2 rows)
```