# How to return a single scalar in postgres plsql from a string_agg query

Tags: postgresql

When I want to return a scalar from a table containing names, e.g.

**names**

```
| name |
| ---- |
| foo  |
| bar  |
```

as `foo,bar` using function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func_names()
    RETURNS CHARACTER VARYING AS
$$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY
        SELECT string_agg(DISTINCT n.name, ',')
        FROM names n;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

but it leads to

> ERROR: cannot use RETURN QUERY in a non-SETOF function

like in [What is a "non-SETOF function"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55688418/what-is-a-non-setof-function) .

But if I remove `QUERY` it says *, NEXT or QUERY expected, got 'SELECT'*.

How to return a simple scalar aggregating those strings inside a table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using [`RETURN TABLE(columns)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-sql.html) as follows :

The [`string_agg()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-aggregate.html) function return `text` so the the returned column should be `TEXT` not `CHARACTER VARYING`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func_names()
    RETURNS TABLE(namee TEXT) AS
$$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY 
        SELECT string_agg(DISTINCT name, ',')
        FROM names;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Result :

```
func_names
bar,foo
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/cHEgR4bu)

Comment: so is there no way to return `character varying`?

Comment: I just wrote it another way, declaring `temp_str`, selecting into it and returning `temp_str`. Now the return type is `character varying`. Here: https://dbfiddle.uk/VQi_I_Wl.  So what is the difference between your solution and mine? Does return type of function matter?

Comment: There is no performance difference among text and character varying(n), apart from increased storage space when using the blank-padded type.

Comment: when you write *text* do you refer to `TABLE(namee TEXT)`?

Comment: Yes, referring to `RETURNS TABLE(namee TEXT)`