# How to use RETURN NEXT in a PL/pgSQL function?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, plpgsql, return-next

I am trying to write a loop in a PL/pgSQL function in PostgreSQL 9.3 that returns a table. I used `RETURN NEXT;` with no parameters after each query in the loop, following examples I found, like:

- [plpgsql error "RETURN NEXT cannot have a parameter in function with OUT parameters" in table-returning function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14039720/)

However, I am still getting an error:

```
ERROR:  query has no destination for result data
HINT:  If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.
```

A minimal code example to reproduce the problem is below. Can anyone please help explain how to fix the test code to return a table?

Minimal example:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test0()
  RETURNS TABLE(y integer, result text)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
DECLARE
  yr RECORD;
BEGIN
  FOR yr IN SELECT * FROM generate_series(1,10,1) AS y_(y) 
  LOOP
    RAISE NOTICE 'Computing %', yr.y;
    SELECT yr.y, 'hi';
    RETURN NEXT;
  END LOOP;
  RETURN;
END
$func$;
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The example given may be wholly replaced with `RETURN QUERY`:

```
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY SELECT y_.y, 'hi' FROM generate_series(1,10,1) AS y_(y)
END;
```

which will be a *lot* faster.

In general you should avoid iteration wherever possible, and instead favour set-oriented operations.

Where `return next` over a loop is unavoidable (which is very rare, and mostly confined to when you need exception handling) you must set `OUT` parameter values or table parameters, then `return next` without arguments.

In this case your problem is the line `SELECT yr.y, 'hi';` which does nothing. You're assuming that the implicit destination of a `SELECT` is the out parameters, but that's not the case. You'd have to use the out parameters as loop variables like @peterm did, use assignments or use `SELECT INTO`:

```
FOR yr IN SELECT * FROM generate_series(1,10,1) AS y_(y) 
LOOP
    RAISE NOTICE 'Computing %', yr.y;
    y := yr.y;
    result := 'hi';
    RETURN NEXT;
END LOOP;
RETURN;
```

Answer (score 6):

What [@Craig already explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27665012/939860).

**Plus**, if you really need a loop, you can have this simpler / cheaper. You don't need to declare an additional record variable and assign repeatedly. Assignments are comparatively expensive in plpgsql. Assign to the `OUT` variables declared in `RETURNS TABLE` directly. Those are visible everywhere in the code and the `FOR` loop can also assign to a list of variables. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-RECORDS-ITERATING)

> The ***target*** is a record variable, row variable, or comma-separated list of scalar variables.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test0()
  RETURNS TABLE(y integer, result text)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
DECLARE
    yr RECORD;  -- now unneeded
BEGIN
   FOR y, result IN
      SELECT g, 'text_'::text || g
      FROM   generate_series(1,10) g
   LOOP
      RAISE NOTICE 'Computing %', y;
      RETURN NEXT;
   END LOOP;
END
$func$;
```

#### Additional points

- Do **not** use the identifier `y` twice (as `OUT` param and column alias) while you can easily avoid it. That's a loaded footgun. If this can't be avoided, table-qualify columns.
- A final `RETURN` without params is good form, but totally optional. When control reaches the final `END`, the complete result is returned automatically.
- `g` in `FROM   generate_series(1,10) g` is both *table alias* and *column alias* automatically,  unless an explicit column alias is given. It is effectively the same as `FROM   generate_series(1,10) g(g)`.

Answer (score 5):

One way to do it

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test0()
 RETURNS TABLE(y integer, result text) AS $$
BEGIN
    FOR y, result IN 
        SELECT s.y, 'hi' result FROM generate_series(1,10,1) AS s(y)
    LOOP
        RETURN NEXT;
    END LOOP;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT * FROM test0();
```

Outcome:

```
|  Y | RESULT |
|----|--------|
|  1 |     hi |
|  2 |     hi |
|  3 |     hi |
|  4 |     hi |
|  5 |     hi |
|  6 |     hi |
|  7 |     hi |
|  8 |     hi |
|  9 |     hi |
| 10 |     hi |
```

Here is a **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/26d41/2)** demo

Comment: Useful, but it'd be nice if you could explain *why* it works, as the original poster is clearly a bit confused about output variables.

Answer (score 0):

For example, you create `person` table, then insert 2 rows into it as shown below:

```sql
CREATE TABLE person (
  id INT,
  name VARCHAR(20),
  age INT
);

INSERT INTO person (id, name, age) 
VALUES (1, 'John', 27), (2, 'David', 32);
```

Now, you can create `my_func()` with a [FOR](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-RECORDS-ITERATING) and `RETURN NEXT` statement as shown below:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func() RETURNS SETOF person AS $$
DECLARE 
  row person%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  FOR row IN SELECT * FROM person LOOP
    RETURN NEXT row; -- Here
  END LOOP;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Then, calling `my_func()` returns 2 rows as shown below:

```sql
postgres=# SELECT * FROM my_func();
 id | name  | age
----+-------+-----
  1 | John  |  27
  2 | David |  32
(2 rows)
```

```sql
postgres=# SELECT my_func();
   my_func
--------------
 (1,John,27)
 (2,David,32)
(2 rows)
```