# How to return custom record with calculated data

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, plpgsql

I want to return a custom empRecord row. How  can I do this? **Please do not change the select statement.** Essentially I just want to return the name of an employee and a new rank.

```
CREATE TABLE employees (
    id integer primary key
    name text,
    rank integer
);

create type empRecord as (
    name text,
    new_rank integer
);

INSERT INTO employees (id, name, rank) VALUES (1, 'james', 5), (2, 'bob', 10), (3, 'Cole', '54');

create or replace function
    testFunc() returns empRecord
as $$
declare
   nrank integer;
   r empRecord;
begin
    for r in select * from employees
    loop
        
        /*
        if (r.rank > 50) THEN
            nrank = r.rank + 30
        elsif (r.rank > 10) THEN
            nrank = r.rank + 20
        else (r.rank > 5) THEN
            nrank = r.rank + 2
        */

        return next (r.name, nrank) -- This part seems to be wrong
    end loop;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

Table I want:

```
+-------+------+
| name  | rank |
+-------+------+
| james |    7 |
| bob   |   30 |
| cole  |   84 |
| TOTAL |  121 |
+-------+------+
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do in your function, It makes no sense. you are passing _addr param and not using it and then looping in employees table to return all rows with rank!! please explain in plain English with sample data and desired output

Comment: @eshirvana Sorry, I've removed `_addr`. i was re-writing a simple version of my question. i forgot to remove it. Essentially I just want to return a new table which the name and rank+5 of the user.

Comment: Why would you use a function for this rather than just `select name, (rank + 5) from employees`?

Comment: @Marc How can I return a custom next. This part: `return next (r.name, nrank)`

Comment: @Marc I will invoke it by doing `select * from testFunc();`

Comment: @Marc The reason why I don't want to do the select statement you said is because I am trying to learn how to return a calculated column data (in this case `new_rank`). This is because in my actual problem I want to use `plpgsql` if statements to calculate `new_rank`. For example if rank is above `5`, add `7`, else add `2`

Comment: why not instead of the whole loop do select name , rank +5  as rank from employees?  if the purpose is to return the values?? you are not necessary using the right application of function and/or custom datatype

Comment: @eshirvana because I dumbed down my actual question to keep it short and simple. I want to return calculated values as part of a record. I can ask a complicated question or a simple question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more typical use of a function would be something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION NEW_RANK(original_rank)
  RETURNS int AS $$
BEGIN
  -- put add'l logic here if you want to do if/then statements, etc.
  RETURN original_rank + 5;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

And then you invoke it like this:

```
select name, NEW_RANK(rank) from employees;
```

But note the function takes a single input and responds with a single output.  That is typically how developers use SQL functions in my experience.

Comment: What if I want to put a total row at the bottom of the table? Refer to question post table example

Comment: Sounds like a separate/new question. But can be done pretty easily w/a `UNION` of two queries, among other ways.

Comment: Is there no way to return next like this `return next ('name', 19)`. Like you can in python, php etc?

Comment: You can do something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27663449/1024832. But as I said, you might be complicating things trying to do too much application logic in your functions. I'm partial to keeping the database pretty "dumb" in terms of the amount of logic employed, and instead concentrating the logic in my programming (Java, Python, etc.). Besides, pretty much everything you're describing can be done more efficiently in SQL than with custom functions.

Comment: Thanks. This was a very simple question where doing it all in the select statement would be easier. But my actual question has a lot more logic behind it.