# PostgreSQL function returning a data cube

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, olap

First off, the iceberg-cube query is defined as in 
[image]

Let's say I have a relation `item,location,year,supplier,unit_sales`,
and I would like to write a `plpgsql` functions as
a wrapper around the query in the image, to specify the parameter `N`,
like so:

```
create or replace function iceberg_query( percentage integer ) 
returns cube
/* Code here */
as
$$
declare
    numrows int;
begin
    select count(*) into numrows from sales;
    select item, location, year, count(*) 
        from sales  
    group by cube(item,location,year)   
    having count(*) >= numrows*percentage/100;
end;
$$ language 'plpgsql'
```

What do I need to add to `Code here`-part, to make this work? How to specify a data cube as a return type in `plpgsql`?

Comment: The code goes between the two dollar signs $$, you need to finish the code already written. No code should be written where that comment lies.

Comment: Please never post text or code as image. One cannot copy/paste from an image. A table definition (`CREATE TABLE` statement as text!) and your version of Postgres would be helpful, too.

Comment: @Lucas: True, the function body *"goes between the two dollar signs"*. But the wrapping `CREATE FUNCTION` statement is *code*, too (SQL DDL code vs. plpgsql). Improvements in both departments were needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your plpgsql function work, you need a `RETURNS` clause matching what you return. And you need to actually *return* something. I suppose:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION iceberg_query ( percentage numeric) 
  RETURNS TABLE (item ?TYPE?, location ?TYPE?, year ?TYPE?, ct bigint)
AS
$func$
DECLARE
    numrows bigint := (SELECT count(*) FROM sales);
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY
   SELECT s.item, s.location, s.year, count(*) 
   FROM   sales s
   GROUP  BY cube(s.item,s.location,s.year)   
   HAVING count(*) >= numrows * percentage / 100;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Replace the placeholders `?TYPE?` with actual (undisclosed) data types.

Call the function with:

```
SELECT * FROM iceberg_query (10);
```

Note how I table-qualify all column names in the query to avoid naming collisions with the new `OUT` parameters of the same name.

And note the use of `numeric` instead of `integer` as pointed out by Scoots in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55240052/postgresql-function-returning-a-data-cube/55241505#comment97216313_55241505).

Related:

- [How to return result of a SELECT inside a function in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7945932/how-to-return-result-of-a-select-inside-a-function-in-postgresql/7945958#7945958)
- [plpgsql error "RETURN NEXT cannot have a parameter in function with OUT parameters" in table-returning function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14039720/plpgsql-error-return-next-cannot-have-a-parameter-in-function-with-out-paramete/14039866#14039866)

Aside: you don't *need* a function for this. This plain SQL query does the same:

```
SELECT s.item, s.location, s.year, count(*)
FROM   sales s
GROUP  BY cube(s.item,s.location,s.year)
HAVING count(*) >= (SELECT count(*) * $percentage / 100 FROM sales);  -- your pct here
```

Provide a numeric literal (`10.0`, not `10`) to avoid integer division and the rounding that comes with it.

Comment: I think you need to typecast the percentage in your query to type numeric. An integer divided by any number will always yield an integer.