# Returning table with specific parameters from a PostgreSQL function

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, return-type

I have this function, with which I would like to return a table, which holds two columns: `game_name` and `follow` (this would be an integer 0 or 1):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.toggle2(uid numeric, gid NUMERIC)
    RETURNS TABLE (
        follow INT,
        game_name TEXT
    )
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
    BEGIN
        IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * 
                  FROM game_follows 
                 WHERE user_id = uid and game_id = gid)
                 THEN
    INSERT INTO game_follows(user_id, game_id) VALUES(uid, gid);
    follow := 1;
  ELSE
     DELETE FROM game_follows WHERE user_id = uid and game_id = gid;
     follow := 0;
  END IF;
 SELECT name INTO game_name FROM games WHERE id = gid;
    END;
$$
;
```

Sadly, the function returns empty values. I am using it as this:

```
SELECT * FROM toggle2(83, 12);
```

Comment: Please always disclose your version of Postgres. Also most helpful: a table definition (`CREATE TABLE` statement) showing data types and constraints. Most importantly, is there a `UNIQUE` constraint or index on `(user_id, game_id)`? And is concurrent write access possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A function declared to `RETURN TABLE` can return ***0-n rows***.
You must actively *return* rows, or nothing will be returned (no row). One way to do this:

```
RETURN NEXT; -- as last line before END;
```

There are other ways, [see the manual.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING)

**However**, it seems you want to return ***exactly one row*** every time. So **rather** use `OUT` parameters:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public toggle2(uid numeric, gid numeric, OUT follow int, OUT game_name text) AS ...
```

Then it's enough to assign those `OUT` parameters, they are returned in the single result row automatically.

See:

- [Returning from a function with OUT parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20762734/returning-from-a-function-with-out-parameter/20763195#20763195)
- [plpgsql error "RETURN NEXT cannot have a parameter in function with OUT parameters" in table-returning function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14039720/plpgsql-error-return-next-cannot-have-a-parameter-in-function-with-out-paramete/14039866#14039866)
- [How to return result of a SELECT inside a function in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7945932/how-to-return-result-of-a-select-inside-a-function-in-postgresql/7945958#7945958)

Comment: More aspects of your function can be improved: not safe against concurrent writes; odd data types; inefficient; naming convention? But that's beyond the actual question - which is otherwise light on details.

Comment: Also: the `IF...` is terrible. Could be rewritten into sane syntax.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter thanks for the response, why I would like to return table is because I would use the data as JSON in my node js backend. With out parameters it returns a string: "(1,'game_name')", which isn't very ideal result, and would rather have table return where it could be as a json format

Comment: @r.Die: No, you still get a *row*. Call with `SELECT * FROM ...` like you did before.

Comment: Thank you for clarification!