# PostgreSQL - How to keep track of time since a condition was true using LAG()?

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime

I have a table like:

| date | value |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-08-05 00:00:45.000 -0500 | 174 |
| 2023-08-05 00:01:46.000 -0500 | 175 |
| 2023-08-05 00:02:46.000 -0500 | 175 |
| 2023-08-05 00:03:45.000 -0500 | 174 |
| 2023-08-05 00:05:59.000 -0500 | 179 |
| 2023-08-05 00:18:45.000 -0500 | 178 |
| 2023-08-05 00:21:55.000 -0500 | 178 |

I want to craft a SELECT query to add a new column "output" that is either "SKIP" or "KEEP" depending on a few different pieces of logic. One particularly troublesome piece has been the following:

> If the time elapsed between the current row and the last "KEEP" row is greater than 5 minutes, then change the current row from SKIP to KEEP.

Desired output:

| date | value | output |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-08-05 00:00:45.000 -0500 | 174 | KEEP |
| 2023-08-05 00:01:46.000 -0500 | 175 | SKIP |
| 2023-08-05 00:02:46.000 -0500 | 175 | SKIP |
| 2023-08-05 00:03:45.000 -0500 | 174 | SKIP |
| 2023-08-05 00:05:59.000 -0500 | 179 | KEEP |
| 2023-08-05 00:18:45.000 -0500 | 178 | KEEP |
| 2023-08-05 00:21:55.000 -0500 | 178 | SKIP |

What I've tried:

```
SELECT *, 
     CASE 
        WHEN (date - LAG(date) OVER (ORDER BY date ASC)) > INTERVAL '5 minutes' THEN 'KEEP',
        WHEN LAG(date) OVER (ORDER BY date) IS NULL THEN 'PUSH'
     ELSE 'SKIP'
     END AS output
from table;
```

I have used the LAG() function within a CASE statement. This works to compare the current row with the previous row, but I can't figure out how to modify it to compare with the *last SKIP* rather than the previous row. (I also used the IS NULL portion to make sure the first value is KEEP.)

For example, the above query will not mark the 5th row as KEEP because it's comparing the 03:45 timestamp to 05:59, which is less than 5 minutes difference. I want it to be KEEP because the last KEEP occurred at (05:59 - 00:45 = 5 minutes 14 seconds) ago.

I hope that all makes sense. I have been struggling with this for a while now so any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot solve this with `lag()` - or any available window function in Postgres for that matter.

The state for each row can depend on all previous rows (while gaps between adjacent rows are below 5 minutes). Gaps of more than 5 minutes reset the count, but while we cannot make assumptions about previous gaps, we really must traverse the whole table to compute the current state reliably. So this lends itself to a procedural approach, rather than a set-based solution. Suggesting a loop in a simple, set-returning PL/pgSQL function:

Create once:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.f_keepers()
  RETURNS TABLE (ts timestamptz, value int, keep bool)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
DECLARE
   threshold timestamptz;
BEGIN
   FOR ts, value IN 
      SELECT t.ts, t.value
      FROM   tbl t
      ORDER  BY t.ts
   LOOP
      IF ts <= threshold THEN  -- also covers null in first iteration
         keep := false;
      ELSE
         keep := true;
         threshold := ts + interval '5 min';
      END IF;
      
      RETURN NEXT;
   END LOOP;
END
$func$;
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM public.f_keepers();
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/vbdJBrxz)

If one state dominates for the vast majority of rows, I would assign that right away and only reassign the rare state.

Related:

- [plpgsql error "RETURN NEXT cannot have a parameter in function with OUT parameters" in table-returning function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14039720/plpgsql-error-return-next-cannot-have-a-parameter-in-function-with-out-paramete/14039866#14039866)

Asides:
Using the column name `ts` for the `timestamptz` column. "date" is just too misleading.
And the result comes in a `boolean` named `keep`, that being the fitting data type.